# Shuffle Function with Checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, shuffle

What I need is a checkbox to activate or deactivate the random playback from tracks in a playlist (datatable). If the checkbox is checked and a playing track ended the next random track should start playing automatically.

Heres my event which is automatically called when a track has ended:

```
// This event is automatically called when a track has ended
private void mePlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check, if the the (last calculated) Index is in the datagrid range
    // -1 is used, cause the indexes starts by 0 not 1
    if (newIndex >= (dgPlayList.Items.Count - 1)) 
    {
        // If the end of the datagrid is reached, set index to 0 for playing the first track
        newIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Is there a following track in the datagrid, then use the next calculated index
        newIndex += 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Set index to: " + newIndex);

    // Tell the media player to use the calculated nexIndex
    mePlayer.Source = new Uri(playList.Rows[newIndex]["Dateiname"].ToString());
    lblFileName.Content = getFileName(playList.Rows[newIndex]["Dateiname"].ToString());

    // Starts to play and set it to play
    mePlayer.Play();
    isPlaying = true;        
}
```

Im pretty new to C# and I just don't know how to integrate that the player plays a random track after a track has ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) class to create a random value.

[define a Random variable outside the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number).

```
Random r = new Random();
```

and use it like this

```
if (cb_Shuffle.IsChecked == true)
{
    newIndex = r.Next(dgPlayList.Items.Count);
}
else
{
    if (newIndex >= (dgPlayList.Items.Count - 1))
    {
        // If the end of the datagrid is reached, set index to 0 for playing the first track
        newIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // Is there a following track in the datagrid, then use the next calculated index
        newIndex += 1;
    }
}
```

then `newIndex` will be a non-negative number less than `dgPlayList.Items.Count`

you should [check if the checkbox is checked or not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) to decide choosing random number or the next track

Comment: Thanks! How do I integrate the `newIndex = r.Next(dgPlayList.Items.Count);` with a checkbox in the above mentioned event? I've created a checkbox in the form and then tried to add something like `if (checkbox_shuffle.checked) ...` - but I alway get an error `Identifier expected; "checked" is a keyword"`.. I want to set the newIndex with the random number only if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: it should be `Checked` not `checked`

Comment: It is `if (cb_Shuffle.IsChecked == true)` and it works like charm! Thanks for your help! :)